# How can I implement Collection/List interface or abstract class in Kotlin?

Tags: list, collections, interface, kotlin, abstract-class

I'm having trouble implementing the `iterator` and `get` `set` functions. (Edit: By trouble I mean that I don't know how to do it and I need help)

In the past, I've inherited from `ArrayList` even though I need a fixed-size collection.
I've also used an `Array` property in my class and added a `get` and a `set` operator funcions, but these two solutions just feel like unnecessary workarounds.

Edit: I just found out that Kotlin itself doesn't have a `List` implementation yet (it uses `ArrayList` instead), So maybe I'm not supposed to be able to Implement it. I'm going to keep this open just in case.

Comment: What kind of trouble?

Comment: I just don't know how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very neat feature in Kotlin that allows you to easily implement the `List` interface by [Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html). Just use the `by` operator on a list property, then the class will delegate all methods of the `List` interface to that property. So, for example, instead of,

```
class Cars {
    private val cars = ArrayList<Car>()
}
```

you write:

```
class Cars(
    private val cars: MutableList<Car> = ArrayList<Car>()
): MutableList<Car> by cars
```

Now `Cars` implements `List`, and can be used just as such:

```
val cars = Cars()
cars.add(Car())
for (car in cars)
    car.vroom()
```